# UIImageView resizes to strange dimensions after the image is set

Tags: ios, swift, camera, interface-builder

There is something weird happening with my image view when I set the image that I retrieve from the camera.

Below I've posted how my constraints are set up in the Interface Builder:
[image: Constraints of the image views]

After I open the camera and add a picture from there everything stays nice, it doesn't matter if fill up the right of left image first, they both get filled fine.

[image]

When I add the second image the view get messed up like the screenshot below. (Have to blur for an NDA we signed)

[image: The messed up view]

I open this viewcontroller on top of an other with the modelPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContent

I've tried recalculating the constraints and telling the views the have to update them:

```
self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
self.panelBoxView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

//after returning from the camera view I try to update them
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.updateViewConstraints()
    self.view.updateConstraints()
    self.panelBoxView.updateConstraints()
}
```

My view in confined in an other view, see the screenshot below for the list:
[image: List of views]

What is going wrong with my views and causing the image views to get this high?

Comment: First, always use super methods to override lifecycle stuff. Second, the problem here is just the switch button misplaced or the length(height) of the images after upload?

Comment: The height of the image views is misplaced. I'll add an image on how it should like to. I do call the super methods, but didn't copy them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Changed the constraints of the imageviews for the top and bottom to be attached to the bottom and top of the Panel View Box. This solved my issues.

My best guess of origin of this problem was the chaining of constraints to be also attached to the bottom and top of the view and there was no ability to have elements "grow".